# How can I store a project or global variable that references an object PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-variable

I am working on an expression that creates an object, Specifically, I am creating a connection to a database (cursor), which remains available until it is closed.
I need the reference to the object to be visible by other expressions.
I have tried several options:
1.- I can create a global, project, variable with:

```
param='hello'
param = QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalScope().variable('param')
```

But it only allows me to store text or numbers.
***How can I store a reference to an object?***

2.- I can create a QgsExpressionContextScope for the project and store the variable.

```
layer=iface.activeLayer()
pry=QgsProject.instance()
exc=pry.createExpressionContext()
ps=pry.createExpressionContextScope() 
ps.setVariable('c',layer,True)
exc.appendScope(ps)
```

Then access it with:
`ps.variable('c')`
But in order to use it I need to be able to access the project scope in another function. **How can I do it?**

Comment: It's not a GIS question but more a Python question, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15702647. So you can store the `id` of the Python object and retrieve it whenever you want as long it exists.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will look into it. However, I would like to know if it is possible to save a variable that references a visible object for expressions using the QGIS API.

Comment: See also : https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/settings.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After researching some of Nyall Dawson's answers to similar questions I found the stable solution, QGIS provides the ability to create variables that store or reference objects.
Then being able to access them outside the context where they were created.
For this we have several contexts: global, project, layer, layout among others.

In the case of the project:

`layer=iface.activeLayer()`
`QgsExpressionContextUtils.setProjectVariable(QgsProject.instance(), 'myvar',layer)`

Then you can then query the variable with:
`QgsExpressionContextUtils.projectScope(pry).variable('myvar')`